# Forwarding Data Passed From a WebSocket

Tags: java, android, tomcat, tcp, websocket

I have set up a websocket between an android application of mine and a tomcat server that is hosted online. My app is supposed to be able to give an IP address and port number of an outside website and use the websocket to contniuasly forward data to the server which will then pass it on and retrieve from whatever this outside website the user specified is.

So my question is, is there a way to pass in the ip address and port number in my request to create a websocket that will tell my server to forward it on to the given IP address?

I hope this all makes sense, I'm still trying to wrap my mind around it myself so let me know if there is something I can explain better.

Comment: Why doesn't your app connect directly to the tomcat server ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused. My app first creates a websocket to connect directly to the tomcat server. I need the tomcat server to forward messages from the app to the address given

Comment: So then tell the server to do so. What is the exact problem? Can't you send requests/commands?

Comment: I guess it's just a new concept for me. My biggest part is setting up the websocket I think. Do I need to send the ip address IN the request to create the websocket to the server? And then once the server has that IP, how can I continuasly forward traffic to that new address?

Comment: Would I forward it in the @OnMessage?

Comment: `IN the request to create the websocket to the server`? I do not understand your scenario. You first create a websocket who connects to the server I think. Then you can do requests. Or is that wrong? And what you want depends completely on the protocol the tomcat server speaks. I do not know that protocol. You have to look in the documentation then you know hoe you have to `talk` with that server.

Comment: `forward`? Your client is not forwarding I would think. Your client just sends messages/requests/commands to the server. I understood that the server should forward.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I am sorry if I am being difficult, I'm struggling to understand the concept too xD The app that I am building is supposed to listen to another app (which it already does) and then send the information to the webserver over the websocket to send to the external website. I want to be able to stream data both back and forth all the way from the external website to the user application that is communicating with my app.

Comment: Is that other app on the same device? Do tomcat servers support the things you want? You are not writing the tomcat server are you?

Comment: I have written a servlet for the server and yes, both of the apps are on the same device. The user device can be anything. My app is just supposed to listen to it and forward it on.